# CSS Border grid layout

Tags: css, border, css-grid

I'm trying to set border for a grid layout with a vertical spanned cell. As suggested in some other forum posts, I set "margin-left: -1px" to avoid double borders (in the case a cell with right border is next to a cell with left border)

The problem is that only one part of the vertical border of the spanned cell is displayed, see example. How to solve it?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 90px 90px 90px;
  grid-template-rows: 24px 24px 27px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="grid-row: span 3; border: solid 1px;margin-left: -1px;">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The negative margin is the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case the problem is arising because the 5 and 8 items come after the 3.

One way round it is to give the 3 item a higher z-index.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 90px 90px 90px;
  grid-template-rows: 24px 24px 27px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item" style="grid-row: span 3; border: solid 1px;margin-left: -1px;z-index: 1;">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would give `.grid-container` the same background color as the border color and use a `gap` of equal width as the border for the cell mentioned, or any other cell requiring the same.

In your specific case, with 3 * 90px grid columns, you will need to limit the width of the grid with `width: max-content`.

**Snippet**, moved the *inline* style to `.special` for clarity...

```css
.grid-container {
  background-color: black; /* added */
  width: max-content;      /* added */
 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 90px 90px 90px;
  grid-template-rows: 24px 24px 27px;
}

.grid-item {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.grid-item.special { /* special cell */
  grid-row: span 3;
  border: solid 1px;
  gap: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item">1</div>
  <div class="grid-item">2</div>
  <div class="grid-item special">3</div>
  <div class="grid-item">4</div>
  <div class="grid-item">5</div>
  <div class="grid-item">7</div>
  <div class="grid-item">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx. The problem is that in my real case the cells can have different background colors and different border colors, so it would not work

Comment: Thanks. `width: max-content;` is the key.